# Count results per category in typeorm/postgresql

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I have a complex query which extract results from database applying various filters. I want to let user know not only how many results were found, but also count them per category, something as shown here:

[image]

Does `typeorm` provides some utils to do it nicely? I'm using pagination so I guess I would need to run several queries to do the grouping and counting for each filter?

My query:

```
 const query = this._homeworkRepository.createQueryBuilder('homework');
    query.leftJoin('homework.author', 'author');
    query.leftJoin('homework.domain', 'domain');
    query.leftJoin('homework.definitions', 'definitions');
    query.leftJoin('homework.theorems', 'theorems');
    query.leftJoin('homework.tags', 'tags');
    query.select([
      'homework.id',
      'homework.slug',
      'homework.createdAt',
      'homework.updatedAt',
      'homework.description',
      'homework.price',
      'homework.solutionFormats',
      'domain.id',
      'domain.slug',
      'domain.name',
      'theorems.id',
      'theorems.slug',
      'theorems.name',
      'definitions.id',
      'definitions.slug',
      'definitions.name',
      'tags.id',
      'tags.slug',
      'tags.name',
    ]);

    if (data.minPrice) {
      query.andWhere('homework.price >= :minPrice', { minPrice: data.minPrice });
    }

    if (data.maxPrice) {
      query.andWhere('homework.price <= :maxPrice', { maxPrice: data.maxPrice });
    }

    if (data.solutionFormats && data.solutionFormats.length) {
      query.andWhere('jsonb_exists_any(homework.solutionFormats, ARRAY[:...solutionFormats])', {
        solutionFormats: data.solutionFormats,
      });
    }

    if (data.domainsIds && data.domainsIds.length) {
      query.andWhere('domain.id IN (:...domainsIds)', { domainsIds: data.domainsIds });
    }

    if (data.theoremsIds && data.theoremsIds.length) {
      if (data.theoremsExact) {
        query.andWhere(
          new Brackets((qb) => {
            data.theoremsIds.forEach((id, index) => {
              qb.andWhere(
                'EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM homework_entity_theorems_theorem_entity WHERE "homeworkEntityId" = homework.id AND "theoremEntityId" = :id' +
                  index +
                  ')',
                {
                  ['id' + index]: id,
                },
              );
            });
          }),
        );
      } else {
        query.andWhere('theorems.id IN (:...theoremsIds)', { theoremsIds: data.theoremsIds });
      }
    }

    if (data.definitionsIds && data.definitionsIds.length) {
      if (data.definitionsExact) {
        query.andWhere(
          new Brackets((qb) => {
            data.definitionsIds.forEach((id, index) => {
              qb.andWhere(
                'EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM homework_entity_definitions_definition_entity WHERE "homeworkEntityId" = homework.id AND "definitionEntityId" = :id' +
                  index +
                  ')',
                {
                  ['id' + index]: id,
                },
              );
            });
          }),
        );
      } else {
        query.andWhere('definitions.id IN (:...definitionsIds)', { definitionsIds: data.definitionsIds });
      }
    }

    if (data.tagsIds && data.tagsIds.length) {
      if (data.tagsExact) {
        query.andWhere(
          new Brackets((qb) => {
            data.tagsIds.forEach((id, index) => {
              qb.andWhere(
                'EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM homework_entity_tags_tag_entity WHERE "homeworkEntityId" = homework.id AND "tagEntityId" = :id' +
                  index +
                  ')',
                {
                  ['id' + index]: id,
                },
              );
            });
          }),
        );
      } else {
        query.andWhere('tags.id IN (:...tagsIds)', { tagsIds: data.tagsIds });
      }
    }

    // NOTE user want to get homeworks from specific favorite list
    if (data.favoriteId) {
      query.leftJoin('homework.favoriteHomeworks', 'favoriteHomeworks');
      query.leftJoin('favoriteHomeworks.favorite', 'favorite');
      query.addSelect(['favoriteHomeworks.id', 'favorite.id', 'favorite.name']);
      query.andWhere('favorite.id = :favoriteId', { favoriteId: data.favoriteId });
    } else if (user.role === Roles.USER) {
      query.leftJoin('homework.favoriteHomeworks', 'favoriteHomeworks');
      query.leftJoin('favoriteHomeworks.favorite', 'favorite');
      query.leftJoin('favorite.user', 'user', 'user.id = :userId', { userId: user.id });
      query.addSelect(['favoriteHomeworks.id', 'favorite.id', 'favorite.name']);
      // NOTE omit hidden homeworks
      query.andWhere('favorite IS NULL OR favorite.name != :hiddenFavoriteListName', {
        hiddenFavoriteListName: 'Ukryte',
      });
    }

 
    return pagination(data, query, ['homework.description'], {
      default: 'homework.id',
      createdAt: 'homework.createdAt',
      updatedAt: 'homework.updatedAt',
      description: 'homework.description',
      domain: 'domain.name',
      theorems: 'theorems.name',
      definitions: 'definitions.name',
      tags: 'tags.name',
      price: 'homework.price',
    });
  }
```

Comment: A native query will do this job nicely.

Comment: sorry what do you mean? Do you maybe have some links/examples which explain how to do it in typorm? I'm pretty new in typeorm and db i ngeneral

Comment: could you please provide your query

Comment: @Ianis see updated question, its a massive query